# Create DropDownList that populates OnFocus using CascadingDropDown

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to populate a dropdownlist when a user clicks it before it drops down? I thought maybe using the CascadingDropDown might work but I cannot get it to work at all.

Comment: Are you referring to the CascadingDropDown from **Ajax Control Toolkit**?

Comment: @Marcus Yes, Ajax - CascadingDropDown.

Comment: Is it mandatory the use of CascadingDropDown?

Comment: @Marcus Nope, it is not mandatory, it was a suggestion by someone.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius I not only need to populate before it drops down but I also need to load an image and load message in other web parts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using an `UpdatePanel` and dropping your `DropDownList` on it?

Then just implement the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of the `DropDownList` to make it reload the next `DropDownList`.  It's the easiest approach if your not gonig to use the CascadingDropDown and it gives you a good idea of how it is all tied together.  Just watch your `ViewState` and disable it if it is not needed.

Here is an example of the asp.net markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="yourFirstDropDownList" runat="server"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="yourFirstDropDownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="yourUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="yourFirstDropDownList"
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged">
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="yourSecondDropDownList" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I was hoping to load it OnFocus. I need populate it before it drops down. Kind of like on demand, but i need to run a server function to get the collection.

Comment: @tszoro So the list isn't based on a previous selected dropdownlist or some other previously defined data that you can trigger off of? Normally triggering off of focus is odd, because you could get focus multiple times and cause a lot of reloading that isn't necessary. Best to trigger off the root of the change.

Comment: Well, it could actually be based on multiple values from other controls on the page. So sometimes it will query a table and other times calls a public function that creates a collection.

Comment: @tszoro You can add multiple triggers to an `UpdatePanel`.  You could just add one to each 'change' of the controls that contain data that could affected it.

Comment: I'll give it try and see what happens.

Comment: Is there a way to call a function when the user clicks the dropdownlist before it expands? I tried the recomendation however there is 20+ dropdownlists.

Comment: I am also trying display a message and show an image as soon as user clicks on the control as well as trying to populate the dropdown before it expands. Is this doable?

Comment: @tszoro it is doable (everything is) but it will be much more work and you will have to handle a lot of the stuff on your own which the `UpdatePanel` is doing for you.  If you think adding 20 triggers is a lot of work, the manual on focus way might be just as much if not more.  Also the OnFocus to load is not very standard and you might have to figure out a lot more UI qwirks to deal with using that method. Try and isolate the trigger as much as possible... 20 drop downs on a page that affect a single control seems to me to be an overly complicated UI but I don't know your context.

Comment: I guess the issue is when the user clicks the DropDownList it loses focus before it expands the dropdown when setting the images and messages in other parts of the page.

Comment: @tszoro how did it go, did this help?

Comment: Your idea would work great, however since the dropdowns are dynamically created and populated I decided to use ajax ModalPopupExtender. This way I can hit the server OnFocus (__doPostBack), run all the necassary code and display with the ModalPopupExtender(with a listbox) using the .Show method being able to set the position right underneath the dropdown that fired it off.